# Grpc server send data to queue ,Nats io

Tags: go, grpc, nats.io

I have a situation where I need to publish  the data from grpc server (streaming )data to

Nats io publisher ,this nats io would be subscribed by many clients

```
          Grpc Server  ----->Nats Io  -->Clients
```

How can I achieve that ,I was able to send data from GRpc server --->Grpc client in go and then was able to publish on nats server

But I don't want to involve the grpc client in between .Any idea how to achieve it

Comment: If you have a gRPC server and NATS clients then you will need something to translate (connect to the gRPC server as a client, receive data and publish via NATS); so I'm not really sure what you are asking here? (of course you can remove the need by using NATS on the server or gRPC on the clients).